# Verma module and vanishing of extension groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensional complex semisimple Lie algebra with Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$.
Let $W$ be the associated Weyl group and let $\Phi$ be its root system.
We write $\Phi^+$ for the set of positive roots in $\Phi$.

Fix a subset of simple roots $I$ and let $W_I$ be the corresponding standard parabolic subgroup of $W$, with longest element $w_I$ and root system $\Phi_I\subseteq \Phi$. Let $\Phi_I^+:=\Phi_I\cap\Phi^+$.

Define
$
\Lambda^+_I := \{\nu \in \mathfrak{h}^*  :  \langle\nu,\alpha^\lor\rangle \in \mathbb{Z}^{\ge 0} \ \text{for all }\alpha \in \Phi^+_I\}.
$

Consider $\lambda \in \Lambda^+_I$ and assume $\lambda$ is integral. We define 
$
{}^IW := \{w\in W: w<s_\alpha w \ \text{for all }\alpha\in I\},
$
where $<$ is the Bruhat ordering on $W$.

Denote by $\Delta$ the simple system corresponding to the positive system $\Phi^+$ in $\Phi$. The orbit $W\cdot\lambda$
contains a unique $\mu\in\mathfrak{h}^*$ that is antidominant in the sense that 
$\langle \mu+\rho,\alpha^{\lor}\rangle\not\in\mathbb{Z}^{>0}$ for all $\alpha\in \Phi^+$, where $\rho = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{\alpha \in \Phi^+} \alpha$.

The set of singular simple roots associated to $\mu$ in $\Delta$ is defined by 
$
{\Sigma_\mu} : = \{\alpha\in \Delta: \langle\mu+\rho,\alpha^\lor\rangle=0\}.
$

The subgroup $W_{\Sigma_\mu} := \{w\in W: w(\mu+\rho)=\mu+\rho\}\subseteq W$ is then the isotropy group of $\mu$.

Let
$
{}^IW^{\Sigma_\mu} : = \{w\in {}^IW: w<ws_\alpha\in {}^IW\ \text{for all }\alpha\in {\Sigma_\mu}\},
$
where $<$ is the Bruhat ordering on $W$.

Let $M(\eta)$ be the Verma module with highest weight $\eta$ and $L(\eta)$ be its unique simple quotient.

> Let $w\in {}^IW^{\Sigma_\mu}$, suppose $\mathrm{Ext}^i_{\mathcal{O}}\left(M(w_Ix\cdot\mu),L(w_Iw\cdot\mu)\right)=\{0\}$ for all $i\ge 0$ and for all $x\in {}^IW^{\Sigma_\mu}-\{w\}$.
>   Does this imply $w=e$?

Comment: Note that Venkataramana's "correction" of the header is wrong in this context where non-Verma modules occur.

Comment: More substantively, I'd start with the case $I=\Delta$. where more is known.   The general case is probably too difficult right now.

Comment: @JIm Humphreys: excuse me: I did not correct the header at all! I corrected some grammar at the end.

Comment: If we consider $I=\Delta$, we get $W_I=W$ and hence ${}^I W=\{e\}$. This implies that ${}^IW^{\Sigma_\mu}=\emptyset$ for nonempty ${\Sigma_\mu}$.

Comment: @Venkataramana:  Sorry to have attributed this change to you.  The string of edits here is hard to follow, and at first I had the impression that you were responsible.    At any rate, the current header is more accurate.    (But motivation for the question is lacking, and I suspect the general case is very difficult.)

Comment: #James Cheung:   I tend to agree with your analysis of the special case, but I still lack motivation to consider the most general case.   And I still suspect it's too hard.  (Maybe special cases are easier, when $W$ is smaller or better known.)

Comment: @JimHumphreys why did you simplify the title? this title is way too non-informative.

Comment: @YCor: The title "Vanishing of extensions between Verma modules" struck me as inaccurate, since only one module involved is usually a Verma module. This title was apparenty expanded by James Cheung, who should provide a more precise one. (Maybe "Vanishing of certain extension groups in the category $\mathcal{O}$"?)

Comment: I did the initial expansion (which you found inaccurate, and you seem to be right), and the second too. The second is vague enough to be fine, isn't it? No need to be precise, but is somewhat targets the topic and flavor of the queston, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is No.
We need the following lemma:

> Lemma: $W_I\cap W_J=W_{I\cap J}$.

to prove the following proposition:

> Proposition: $e\in {}^IW^{\Sigma_\mu}\iff I\cap \Sigma_\mu=\emptyset$.

Proof: Recall that ${}^IW^{\Sigma_\mu} : = \{w\in {}^IW: w<ws_\alpha\in {}^IW\ \text{for all }\alpha\in {\Sigma_\mu}\}$.
Suppose $e\in {}^IW_{[\lambda]}^{\Sigma_\mu}$, we have $s_\alpha\in {}^IW$ for all $\alpha\in \Sigma_\mu$. Then $W_{\Sigma_\mu}\subseteq {}^IW$. Since $W_I\cap {}^IW=\{e\}$ and , we get $W_{\Sigma_\mu}\cap W_I=\{e\}$. Note that $W_{I\cap\Sigma_\mu}=W_{\Sigma_\mu}\cap W_I$ and hence $W_{I\cap\Sigma_\mu}=\{e\}$. This implies that $I\cap\Sigma_\mu=\emptyset$.

Suppose $I\cap\Sigma_\mu=\emptyset$. We have $W_{\Sigma_\mu}\cap W_I=W_{I\cap\Sigma_\mu}=\{e\}$. Suppose $W_{\Sigma_\mu}\not\subseteq {}^IW$ on contrary, there is $w\in W_{\Sigma_\mu}, w\not\in {}^IW$. Let $w=w_1w^{1}$ where $w_1\in W_I$ and $w^1\in {}^IW$. Since $w\not\in {}^IW$, we have $w_1\neq e$. Note that $w_1\le w$ implies $w_1\in W_{\Sigma_\mu}$ since $W_{\Sigma_\mu}$ is a parabolic subgroup of $W$. This contradicts to the fact that $W_{\Sigma_\mu}\cap W_I=\{e\}$. This implies $W_{\Sigma_\mu}\subseteq {}^IW$. In particular, $e<es_\alpha\in {}^IW$ for all $\alpha\in\Sigma_\mu$. Therefore, $e\in {}^IW^{\Sigma_\mu}$.

It is easy to construct example with $I\cap \Sigma_\mu\neq\emptyset$, which does not allow us to have $e\in {}^IW^{\Sigma_\mu}$.